# Azure DevOps Release pipeline with multiple artifacts and stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-artifacts

Is it possible to have a single release pipeline with multiple artifacts that will trigger separate stages conditionally.

Example:

**BuildPipelineA** builds **/PathA** from **AppRepo**, **Dev** branch and publishes the artifact **ArtifactA**. **ArtifactA** should be deployed to **stage A**.

**BuildPipelineB** builds **/PathB** from **AppRepo**, **Dev** branch and publishes the artifact **ArtifactB**. **ArtifactB** should be deployed to **stage B**.

Both the artifacts are in one release pipeline and the problem I have is when I queue the build for **BuildPipelineA**, after the successful build, the release pipeline is created and ArtifactA is deployed to Stage A, Artifact B (last successful build artifact) is deployed to stage B.

[image: Example Pipeline Image]

What I am trying to achieve is, since **BuildPipelineB** is not triggered and no latest **Artifact B** is published, it should not be deployed to **stage B** when **ArtifactA** triggered the release and vice versa

Comment: It sounds like these should be separate pipelines.

Comment: Hi Daniel
Yes this can be achieved with separate pipeline but my requirement is to do it in single pipeline

Comment: Why is that a requirement? Two independent application deployments should be handled in separate pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am trying to achieve is, since BuildPipelineB is not triggered and no latest Artifact B is published, it should not be deployed to stage B when ArtifactA triggered the release and vice versa

Based on your description about the situation(same repo, same branch), I am afraid that there is no such built-in feature can directly meet your requirements.

For a workaround, you can set the condition in Stage -> Jobs.

You can use this variable to make judgments : **RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS**.

It represents the artifact name that triggered the release.

Here is an example:

Release Stages:

[image]

Condition:  `eq(variables['RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS'], '_PipelineA')`

[image]

When the Pipeline A, trigger the Pipeline, it will run the agent job in Stage1 and it will skip the agent job in Stage2.

Comment: Thank you for your response Kevin. The above condition skips the deployment but displays the stage status as succeeded and executes the next sequence stage.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported to have multiple artifacts in one CD and have only a specific artifact been deployed to one stage.

[image: Azure Dev Ops]

Here is photo, select from multiple artifacts which one you want to be included in deployment to azure resource.